# Python 3 - enhance writelines function to always add new line

Tags: python

New to coding, trying to learn some basics.  Trying to get this to work in Python 3.x

I want to enhance the writelines function to always add \n so I don't have to use it after every string.  I'm writing hundreds of lines.

Below my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
def writextra(self, string):
    self.writelines(string + '\n')
    return None

text_file=open('some_file.txt', 'w')
text_file.writextra('hello world')
text_file.writextra('line two')


Error is:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writextra'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick fix, you should add to your function not `self` parameter but, for example `f_out` and then call your function for example `writeextra(text_file, 'hello world')`:

```
def writextra(f_out, string):
    return f_out.writelines(string + '\n')

text_file=open('some_file.txt', 'w')
writextra(text_file, 'hello world')
writextra(text_file, 'line two')
```

Comment: Wooohooo, thank you!  That total works and makes sense.  Wish this site had a built in tipping mechanism

Comment: @BennyMcFarley It has, in the form of upvotes/accepting answer ;)

Comment: thanks-- first time asking here, trying to figure out how to accept the answer :) I did upvote!

Comment: @BennyMcFarley you upvote by clicking the ^ sign next to the answer and accept clicking the ✓ sign.